# Inject env variables from docker-compose into Angular4 app

Tags: angular, docker, environment-variables, docker-compose, angular-cli

I build a simple Angular4 app which get its data from a REST-API.

I deploy the app with docker-compose but before I need to set the URL/Hostname to the API manually in my service module.
During the dev I simply used 'localhost' and it does the job.

In the API I'am able inject the correct hostname via docker-compose (section *environment*) since it runs on the server but this is not possible for angular.

Are there any best practices / guides for injecting the hostname / URL into a angular-cli app from docker-compose?

Comment: See if this helps? http://tarunlalwani.com/post/simple-parameterized-config-files-docker/

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this is to extract all configuration into a separate angular service that is responsible of serving configuration. Inside this new service hardcode these values to env placeholders. For example:

```
apiUrl = $API_URL
```

Now change the CMD inside your DockerFile to run a script `startup.sh`.

Create this script and add it into the Docker Image using `ADD startup.sh startup.sh`.

Inside startup.sh you can envoke `envsubst < "path-to-service-file" > "path-to-service-file"` to substitute the placeholder with the env variable value. After envsubst command start your angular application

Answer (score 2):

Thank you *yamenK* for you solution with the bash script and *Tarun* for a similar solution.

I found another way to avoid the need of the information about the Api Url in the angular app.
I added an nginx web server to my docker-compose and link it to my api and the app.

```
nginx:
build: ./nginx
...
links:
  - app
  - api
```

In the nginx default.conf I use multiple *locations* to route the requests.

```
location /api {
proxy_pass http://api:6000/api;
....
}
location / {
proxy_pass http://angular:4200/;
...
}
```

Then in the angular app I use relative urls.